# Is Regularization a must for target-based encoders?

Tags: regularization, categorical-encoding, target-encoders

> The most stable and accurate Categorical encoders are target-based encoders. Target encoding is the process of replacing a categorical value with the mean of the target variable. From the [Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/benchmarking-categorical-encoders-9c322bd77ee8) **4. Regularization is a must for target-based encoders.**

Several Kaggle Competitors use mean encoding and Target encoding with regularization to predict much better and rise through ranks in the leaderboard.

**Why is regularization used in target encoders? Is regularization a must?**

Comment: Could you share source of those quotes?